# Framebox around fraction

Tags: framed, fractions

I'm trying to box the fraction `1/6`, and so I write

```
 \framebox{\dfrac{1}{6}}
```

However when I do this I end up with the formatting all off and the framebox and fraction don't show up at all. Is there another way to put a box around the fraction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This worked for me: `\framebox{$\dfrac{1}{6}$}` (using `framed` and `amsmath` packages). Have you really used `\framebox{\dfrac{1}{6}}`? That gives errors! Please don't post such fragments only, give a full `.tex` document instead!

Comment: Yeah, I copy/pasted your line and it didn't show at all. I'm using ShareLatex, if that makes any difference. I think some things don't show up there because I've had issues with shapes and `\log` as well.

Comment: Sigh, `ShareLaTeX` ... I am pretty sure that your version must give compilation errors.

Comment: Would you recommend another online LaTeX editor? I need to keep it all online because I'm constantly flipping computers. However if there's a light software I might be able to download it

Comment: No, I don't recommend such editors at all...

Comment: Why not simply `\boxed{\frac{1}{6}}`?

Comment: That also doesn't work.

Comment: have you used `\usepackage{amsmath}`?  that is needed for many math elements including `\log` and `\dfrac`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using it now. Still not working.

Comment: @AnonE.Muss: Then post your document here, as I have already asked you once! `Not working` is no precise description!

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget the $-signs?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\framebox{$\dfrac{1}{6}$}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

which isn't pretty but is a framebox with a fraction in it.

Comment: I asked that already in my first comment right below the post ;-)

Comment: Oops, sorry.  Feel free to downvote.  Or if you'd prefer, I'll remove my answer.

Comment: I rarely downvote answers (or questions)... but we have some users here which downvote quite often... I **don't** say this is to be downvoted at all... keep it as you like

Comment: I guess I should read the comments more carefully....

Comment: Well, many (high rep) users post nearly identical comments after similar comments has been made already to the post -- the difference is: The comment of high rep users are upvoted, others aren't although they have been written earlier (and aren't not wrong) ... so much for 'reading comments more carefully' ;-)

Comment: Of course I meant `aren't wrong` -- the double negation is a typo ;-) So much for writing comments carefully :D